# Spider wget only returning directories but no files

Tags: bash, wget

I create a non interactive cookie in first command so that i can go in passwordless after to get all pages in the second wget command.

```
wget --no-check-certificate --save-cookies cookies.txt --keep-session-cookies  --post-data 'user=me&password=mepassword' --delete-after https://site.address.com/php/index.php?site=abc&var=tor&dir=200219&date=2019-02-20

wget --no-check-certificate --load-cookies cookies.txt -r --spider https://site.address.com/php/index.php?site=abc&var=tor&dir=200219&date=2019-02-20
```

However, only dirs are returned

Comment: On Linux you must add quote for the url: "htxps://my_url.com/etc?etc=...." because you have special characters in it (? &).

Comment: Swing and a miss unfortunately. Had also tried it with the base address (i.e no & parts). Thanks for the attempt.